# Create all possible combinations of text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need help in TSQL to create all possible combinations from text.

I have data like below

```
Input
A
B
C
```

Need result like below

```
Output
ABC
BCA
CAB
CBA
BAC
ACB
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `join`:

```
select i1.col, i2.col, i3.col
from input i1 join
     input i2
     on i2.col not in (i1.col) join
     input i3
     on i3.col not in (i1.col, i2.col);
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/PJL12765) is a rextester for this solution.

EDIT:

It occurs to me that you might want to vary the length of `input` and that you really want strings with all the permutations.

If so, this can be handled with a recursive CTE:

```
with input as (
      select v.x
      from (values ('a'), ('b'), ('c')) v(x)
     ),
     cte as (
      select cast(x as varchar(max)) as str, 1 as len
      from input
      union all
      select cte.str + i.x, len + 1
      from cte join
           input i
           on cte.str not like '%' + i.x + '%'
     )
select top (1) with ties str
from cte
order by len desc;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/33971) is a SQL Fiddle with this solution.

Comment: @Vikram . . . Which is not working?  I've provided a SQL Fiddle for the second solution, so it definitely works.  I've provided a rextester for the first, and it definitely works.

Comment: This works! Can we make the query generic, i mean if there are more values like - a,b,c,d,e,f

Comment: @Vikram . . . The second version is generic.

Answer (score 0):

i think cross can generate all the possible combination

```
 select t2.c+t3.col from 
(select t1.col+t2.col as c
from t t1 cross join
     t t2
     ) as t2 cross join
     t t3
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7a22b3c1f5fe81be1e2f3ec09311bd87